# session_start exhausts memory

Tags: php, session

`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 13374929 bytes) in script.php on line 2`

Line 2 is
`session_start();`.

Sessions are stored in `memcached` daemon (set via `php.ini session.save_path`
with default memcached settings (1mb for entry max), meaning session data itself is not supposed to be that big.

Suggestions for debugging?

Comment: Well, maybe the question is a bit invalid and that is nothing to do with the session itself and the memory is allocated somewhere before it get's to the session_start line.

Comment: its generally advised against using memcached for session related purposes.

Comment: PHP version? Environment in general?

Comment: centos 6.3 with php 5.3.3, no suhosin, pecl-memcache (not d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session_start itself has no memory overflows.
The error appeared there since this was the straw that broke the camel's back
and nearly the max available memory was allocated already before getting to that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
session.save_handler = memcache    
session.save_path="tcp://YOURSERVER:PORT?persistent=1&amp;weight=1&amp;timeout=1&amp;retry_interval=10"
```

Try to set your php.ini config to something like that...